# Could not load module 'react/addons'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, brunch

I have Jest+Enzyme setup to test my React app and I use brunch to build the app. When I run brunch, I got following error

`Processing of node_modules/enzyme/build/react-compat.js failed. Error: Could not load module 'react/addons' from '/home/Project/node_modules/enzyme/build'. Possible solution: run`npm install`.`

But I have no trouble running Jest. I use yarn and `yarn install` does nothing as I have all packages installed. What is this missing `react/addons` package?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by telling brunch to ignore my test files

```
conventions: {
  ignored: [
    '**/*.test.js'
  ]
}
```